# rails gem zxing always failed deployed on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, barcode, zxing

i'm use this gem [zxing](https://github.com/ecin/zxing.rb) for decode my barcode png. In my local machine is work properly, but when i'm try deploy to heroku. Heroku always refused this gem. Why, whats wrong?

```
error messages : Timed out compiling Ruby app (15 minutes)
```

if i remove this gem, deploy is working. Whether because this gem using "JRuby"?

i'm need this gem for decode my barcode png, please help me

in this case i'm using ruby on rails

Answer (score 0):

It's the first thing on the zxing github page:

> JRuby wrapper for ZXing 1D/2D barcode image processing library.

With default settings, Heroku uses MRI Ruby, but it is possible to use JRuby, according to [this article](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/12/13/run_jruby_on_heroku_right_now).

Comment: are you known gem pure ruby for decode barcode png @zwippie ?